# Storyboard execution on Mouse Over

Tags: wpf, animation, storyboard, expression-blend

I've developed a WPF application in Expression Blend, a simple button attach with a storyboard with bounce effect.

So far so good, now I want my button to bounce when my mouse enters on it, it does. But it keeps doing that. I move mouse once and after bouncing again falls into the mouse region (I am not moving the mouse, mouse cursor is still) and starts bouncing again.

This is the whole code that I am using

```
    <Window.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="Storyboard1">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)" Storyboard.TargetName="button">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="0"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)" Storyboard.TargetName="button">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                    <BounceEase EasingMode="EaseIn"/>
                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="-29">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                    <BounceEase EasingMode="EaseIn"/>
                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</Window.Resources>
<Window.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Storyboard1}"/>
    </EventTrigger>
</Window.Triggers>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="51" Margin="76,100,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="130" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <Button.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform/>
                <SkewTransform/>
                <RotateTransform/>
                <TranslateTransform/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </Button.RenderTransform>
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseEnter">
                <ei:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource Storyboard1}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

Just copy paste it in your xaml window and you'll good to go.

Keep the mouse on the top corner of mouse. You'll see the problem.

Thanks

Comment: Would be useful to see some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing that pops out is that you're moving the button by 29px down when it's 51px tall. Chances are the button moves away from the mouse and starts moving back to reverse the animation.

You can work around this by reworking the button and animation:
 - place the button in a container (grid, stackpanel - anything that works for you)
 - make the container's background "Transparent" (which is NOT the same as "null")
 - make the button align to the bottom of that container
 - make the animation trigger on the container and change the container's height
The result is that when the button moves away the mouse is still over its container so the animation doesn't stop and reverse.
 - control animation behavior with AutoReverse and RepeatBehavior

--
This is obviously not the whole code you're using (where's the "i" namespace declaration?) so I can't see your problem on my end.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, if you want to reproduce the problem, then the "I:" is for System.Windows.Interactivity

Answer (score 0):

Let's take this button animation as example:

```
<Grid>  
    <Button HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="Test  ">
      <Button.RenderTransform>
        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1.0" ScaleY="1.0" />
      </Button.RenderTransform> 
      <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
          <Style.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
              <EventTrigger.Actions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                  <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleX" To="2.0" />
                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleY" To="2.0" />
                  </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
              </EventTrigger.Actions>
            </EventTrigger>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
              <BeginStoryboard>
                  <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleX" To="1.0" />
                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleY" To="1.0" />
                  </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
          </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
      </Button.Style>     
    </Button>
  </Grid>
```

So when your mouse enters the button area, it grows, and when the mouse leaves, it shrinks back.

By default, a StoryBoard's:

- `AutoReverse = False`, if true the animation reverts as soon as it's over.
- `FillBehavior = HoldEnd`, which makes the button's appearence stay as how it looks once the animation is over (i.e: the button will remain 2x bigger as long as you keep your mouse above the button). If set to `Stop`, it will revert back to its original state as soon as the animation finishes (without animation, which is what is different from AutoReverse).
- `RepeatBehavior = 1x`, you can set this to a `TimeSpan`, `nx` where **n** is the number of times you want the animation repeated, or `Forever` and it will loop forever.

You should check that these settings haven't been tampered with.

And last but not least, make sure the logic tied to your animation makes sense and doesn't induce a loop (which would, in turn, make the animation loop). For example if you animate based on the mouse being over an element, and the animation moves the element, then your mouse isn't over the element anymore, and thus the animation reverts, bringing back the button under the mouse, etc, forever.

Comment: I've updated the question, will you please look at it now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try to put the mouse inside a canvas with a transparent (not null) background and animate the button when the mouse gets over the canvas. The button would leave its position but the canvas wouldn't. You could use that solution inside a template control, for example.